# Beamer pdflatex problem

Tags: beamer

When I run

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
1
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with PDFLaTeX, I receive the error

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file C:/TeX/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/beamer/beamericonarti
cle.tex): unknown type of image
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What needs to be fixed?

Thanks,
David

Here is the complete log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6730 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.2)  2 JUL 2018 08:33
entering extended mode
**C:/Math/TeX/Presentations/Marion/BeamerIntro.tex
(C:/Math/TeX/Presentations/Marion/BeamerIntro.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count80
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count81
\c@beamerpauses=\count82

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count83
\beamer@minimum=\count84
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box27
\beamer@modecount=\count85
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
\headdp=\dimen102
\footheight=\dimen103
\sidebarheight=\dimen104
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen105
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen106
\beamer@animht=\dimen107
\beamer@animdp=\dimen108
\beamer@animwd=\dimen109
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen110
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen111
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen112
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen113
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen114
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen115
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen116
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen117
\beamer@lastskip=\skip41
\beamer@areabox=\box28
\beamer@animcurrent=\box29
\beamer@animshowbox=\box30
\beamer@sectionbox=\box31
\beamer@logobox=\box32
\beamer@linebox=\box33
\beamer@sectioncount=\count86
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count87
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count88
\beamer@sectionmax=\count89
\beamer@totalheads=\count90
\beamer@headcounter=\count91
\beamer@partstartpage=\count92
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count93
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count94
\beamer@animationtempa=\count95
\beamer@animationtempb=\count96
\beamer@xpos=\count97
\beamer@ypos=\count98
\beamer@ypos@offset=\count99
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count100
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count101
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count102
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count103
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count104

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoptions.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip42
\beamer@paperheight=\skip43

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count105
\Gm@cntv=\count106
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count107
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen118
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen119
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen120
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen122
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen123
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen124
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen126
\Gin@req@width=\dimen127
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen128
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen129

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box34

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen130
\pgf@y=\dimen131
\pgf@xa=\dimen132
\pgf@ya=\dimen133
\pgf@xb=\dimen134
\pgf@yb=\dimen135
\pgf@xc=\dimen136
\pgf@yc=\dimen137
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count108
\c@pgf@countb=\count109
\c@pgf@countc=\count110
\c@pgf@countd=\count111
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count112
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count113
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen138
\pgfmath@count=\count114
\pgfmath@box=\box35
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex
) (C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.cod
e.tex))) (C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count115
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen139
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen140
\pgf@picminy=\dimen141
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen142
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen143
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen144
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen145
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen146
\pgf@xx=\dimen147
\pgf@xy=\dimen148
\pgf@yx=\dimen149
\pgf@yy=\dimen150
\pgf@zx=\dimen151
\pgf@zy=\dimen152
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen153
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen154
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen155
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen156
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box36
\pgf@hbox=\box37
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box38
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count116
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen157
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen158
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen159
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen160
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen161
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen162
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count117
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box39
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\xxcolor.sty
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count118
\XC@countmixins=\count119
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `atbegshi' (already loaded).
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen163
\Hy@linkcounter=\count120
\Hy@pagecounter=\count121

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count122

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `implicit' set `false' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4509.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4514.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4517.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4524.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4529.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode OFF; no redefinition of LaTeX internals.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4762.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count123

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5115.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen164
\Fld@menulength=\count124
\Field@Width=\dimen165
\Fld@charsize=\dimen166
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6369.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6374.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6377.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6384.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6389.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6394.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6439.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6443.
\Hy@abspage=\count125


Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 (C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count126
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count127

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaserequires.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecompatibility.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasefont.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks26
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\sansmathaccent.sty
Package: sansmathaccent 2013/03/28

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetranslator.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator.sty
Package: translator 2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemisc.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoverlay.sty
\beamer@argscount=\count128
\beamer@lastskipcover=\skip44
\beamer@trivlistdepth=\count129
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetitle.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasesection.sty
\c@lecture=\count130
\c@part=\count131
\c@section=\count132
\c@subsection=\count133
\c@subsubsection=\count134
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframe.sty
\beamer@framebox=\box40
\beamer@frametitlebox=\box41
\beamer@zoombox=\box42
\beamer@zoomcount=\count135
\beamer@zoomframecount=\count136
\beamer@frametextheight=\dimen167
\c@subsectionslide=\count137
\beamer@frametopskip=\skip45
\beamer@framebottomskip=\skip46
\beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\skip47
\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\skip48
\beamer@envbody=\toks27
\framewidth=\dimen168
\c@framenumber=\count138
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseverbatim.sty
\beamer@verbatimfileout=\write4
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframesize.sty
\beamer@splitbox=\box43
\beamer@autobreakcount=\count139
\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\dimen169
\beamer@frametitletoks=\toks28
\beamer@framesubtitletoks=\toks29
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframecomponents.sty
\beamer@footins=\box44
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecolor.sty
\beamer@bg@ht=\dimen170
\beamer@bg@wd=\dimen171
\beamer@bg@dp=\dimen172
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenotes.sty
\beamer@frameboxcopy=\box45
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetoc.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetemplates.sty
\beamer@sbttoks=\toks30

(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseboxes.sty
\bmb@box=\box46
\bmb@colorbox=\box47
\bmb@boxshadow=\box48
\bmb@boxshadowball=\box49
\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\box50
\bmb@temp=\dimen173
\bmb@dima=\dimen174
\bmb@dimb=\dimen175
\bmb@prevheight=\dimen176
)
\beamer@blockheadheight=\dimen177
))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tools\enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks31
)
\c@figure=\count140
\c@table=\count141
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenavigation.sty
\beamer@section@min@dim=\dimen178
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetheorems.sty
(C:\TeX\localtexmf\tex\latex\Myfiles\amslatex\math\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\TeX\localtexmf\tex\latex\Myfiles\amslatex\math\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(C:\TeX\localtexmf\tex\latex\Myfiles\amslatex\math\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\ex@=\dimen179
))
(C:\TeX\localtexmf\tex\latex\Myfiles\amslatex\math\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen180
)
(C:\TeX\localtexmf\tex\latex\Myfiles\amslatex\math\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count142
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 211.
\uproot@=\count143
\leftroot@=\count144
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 307.
\classnum@=\count145
\DOTSCASE@=\count146
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 382.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
\big@size=\dimen181
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568.
\macc@depth=\count147
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count148
\dotsspace@=\muskip11
\c@parentequation=\count149
\dspbrk@lvl=\count150
\tag@help=\toks33
\row@=\count151
\column@=\count152
\maxfields@=\count153
\andhelp@=\toks34
\eqnshift@=\dimen182
\alignsep@=\dimen183
\tagshift@=\dimen184
\tagwidth@=\dimen185
\totwidth@=\dimen186
\lineht@=\dimen187
\@envbody=\toks35
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks36
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2666.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2667.
)
(C:\TeX\localtexmf\tex\latex\Myfiles\amslatex\amscls\amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\thm@style=\toks37
\thm@bodyfont=\toks38
\thm@headfont=\toks39
\thm@notefont=\toks40
\thm@headpunct=\toks41
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks42
)
\c@theorem=\count154
)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasethemes.sty))
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerthemedefault.sty
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerfontthemedefault.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamercolorthemedefault.sty)
(C:\TeX\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file C:/TeX/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/beamer/beamericonarti
cle.tex): unknown type of image
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you show the complete .log file?

Comment: Thanks for adding the log file. I just compared it to my own log file and it looks fairly good - the packages seem all up to date. I don't really know where the problem is, maybe some problem with the installed beamer package? Maybe uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: The uninstall and reinstall worked.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by the OP